# How can I convert an array of characters to an integer (for 2 or more digits)

Tags: c++, c++11

The array has to be entered by the user, and not specified in the app itself.

```
char coeff[20];
char expo[20];
for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
    cin >> coeff[i];
    cin >> expo[i];
}
```

When i enter a number in the `cin >> coeff[i]` , it doesn't let me enter more than one digit, is there a way to enter more than 1 digit and still be saved in it in the variable?

PS. I'm forced into using an array of characters here and not integers

Comment: Why not use arrays of `int` instead?

Comment: I'm not allowed to do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* your professor wants you to read in text, and then convert that text to a number. This is a *silly* requirement.

The sensible program would `>>` into `int`s directly

```
int coeff;
int expo;
std::cin >> coeff >> expo;
```

To read it into intermediate text *safely* you could

```
std::string coeff_s;
std::string expo_s;
std::cin >> coeff_s >> expo_s;
int coeff = std::stoi(coeff_s);
int expo = std::stoi(expo_s);
```

However I predict that your professor will insist on using raw `char[]` and not `std::string`. You have to be more careful (prior to C++20) with that, specifying the length of the `char[]`.

```
char coeff_s[20];
char expo_s[20];
std::cin >> std::setw(20) >> coeff_s >> std::setw(20) >> expo_s;
int coeff = std::atoi(coeff_s);
int expo = std::atoi(expo_s);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're storing it in char array. Change the type of `coeff` and `expo` to the right one. Eg: `int coeff[20]` if you expect to store 20 ints.

Comment: yeah but I can't right now cause I'm forced into using an array of characters here

Comment: I don't know why you're forced? Are you expecting an integer of potentially 20 digits, and this is your attempt to capture that?

Comment: It's for a homework and the professor wants us to use an array of characters and not an array of integers in it

Answer (score 0):

This is technically possible but with limitation. In C++ `char` size is usually 1 byte (check first comment) while `int` size is 4 bytes, so the largest value you can store in a `char` is maximum `255` (check first comment) because `255` is the largest number that can be represented with only 1 byte.

So in the `for` loop you can use a new `int` variable to store in it the user input, and then store the bytes in the `char` variable.
And when trying to get the stored integer cast it to an `int` like:

```
char coeff[20]; 
char expo[20]; 
for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++) { 
    int x = 0;
    cin>>x;
    coeff[i] = (char) x;
    cout<<(int) coeff[0];
}
```

Comment: On most platforms, the largest value you can store in a `char` is `127`, not `255`. The ISO C++ standard specifies that it is implementation-defined whether a `char` is signed or unsigned. On most platforms, it is signed.

Comment: You are right. The limitation is the size of int

Comment: I think that might work for me in this situation, thank you

Comment: If this helped consider adding this as an accepted answer. But its important to understand the reason why this works. You can check this video for an easy explanation https://youtu.be/zB9RI8_wExo

Comment: I just asked if I can do it and apparently I am not allowed to do so, I have to enter it in a character

Comment: In order to understand your solution, I believe it is important to mention that using `operator >>` with a `char` type has a very different meaning than using it with an `int` type, as the former reads a single character, whereas the latter reads an entire number. Therefore, you may want to add this to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend directly using int variables instead of char arrays. But as you have to do it for your homework, I found a way to input data into a char array:

```
istream& operator>> (istream& is, char char_array[INT_MAX]) // INT_MAX means the maximum value for an int
{
    std::string s; is >> s;

    if (s.size() > 20) s = s.substr(0, 20);

    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        char_array[i] = s[i];
    }
    return is;
}
```

Here I am overloading the operator >> to work with char arrays of size INT_MAX.

Then in your main function, you can simply say:

```
int main()
{
    char char_array[20]{};

    std::cin >> char_array;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(char_array); i++)
    {
        std::cout << char_array[i];
    }
}
```

As simple as that. Also according to the code that you submitted, don't do the following:

```
using namespace std;
```

...as it is considered as bad practice.
I know there are better ways than this but this is just my idea.